# trying to understand why I keep getting this error come up

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've been watching a freecodecamp video about selenium I python and this method he uses doesn't work for me and I can't see why

```
class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"C:\SeleniumDrivers"):
       self.driver_path = driver_path
       os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
       super(Booking, self).__init__()

    def land_first_page(self):
       self.get('https://www.booking.com')
```

Comment: Well, what error _do_ you get?

Comment: sorry its not really a error that I don't know. Its just I don't understand why I get it. selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you missed the code or was missed in the video - the path separator is missing in this code. so when joining the path, path separator need to be there(example --> : for mac and ; for windows) pls refer to the comments in the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"C:\SeleniumDrivers"):
       self.driver_path = driver_path
       os.environ['PATH'] +=  os.pathsep + self.driver_path # os.pathsep is missing,i.e add chromedriver path the system path.
       super(Booking, self).__init__()

    def land_first_page(self):
       self.get('https://www.booking.com')
```

also ensure that chromedriver has been downloaded and copied to C:\SeleniumDrivers.